# How can add older version of sdk?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem in installing the older API version in android studio 2,3. there is no option in SDK setting to install an older version. My virtual machine warns that you must have a lower version. How can I add older API?
This image relates to the error during the building:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Provide more information please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

in your project's Build.gradle to

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

and you are good to go. Cheers :)